# Ping works, wget, curl and apt do not... firewall disabled to make sure not the problem

Tags: networking

So, as the message says, there is no firewall running at all at present but curl/wget do not work while ping does (also, I am SSHd into the machine and apache2 works so it can receive requests on port 80). This is a mystery for the ages! Here are some hopefully informative tidbits...

I am certain that it is not a firewall issue (firewall totally disabled)

**My /etc/network/interfaces**

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
auto lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#auto eno2
#iface eno2 inet static

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto eno2
iface eno2 inet manual
bond-master bond0
bond-primary eno2

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
bond-mode active-backup
bond-miimon 100
bond-slaves none
```

**restarting networking fails**

```
systemctl restart networking.service
Job for networking.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status networking.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

**here are the errors I get**

```
systemctl status networking.service
â networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/networking.service.d
           ââ50-insserv.conf-$network.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-02-08 13:23:08 EST; 13s ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 28918 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 28913 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] && udevadm settle (code=exited, status=0/S
 Main PID: 28918 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 08 13:23:08 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Feb 08 13:23:08 ubuntu sh[28913]: Unknown interface inet
Feb 08 13:23:08 ubuntu sh[28913]: Unknown interface loopback
Feb 08 13:23:08 ubuntu ifup[28918]: Unknown interface inet
Feb 08 13:23:08 ubuntu ifup[28918]: Unknown interface loopback
Feb 08 13:23:08 ubuntu systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 08 13:23:08 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
Feb 08 13:23:08 ubuntu systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 08 13:23:08 ubuntu systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

**Updates**

Thanks @JohnRonald, I updated the iface line and that succeeded in restarting networking but it did not fix the curl/wget problem.

Here is the curl error @raj

```
--2021-02-08 14:56:03-- (try: 6) 
reddit.com Connecting to www.reddit.com (www.reddit.com)|151.101.1.140|:80... failed: Connection timed out. 
Connecting to www.reddit.com (www.reddit.com)|151.101.65.140|:80... failed: Connection timed out. 
Connecting to www.reddit.com (www.reddit.com)|151.101.129.140|:80..
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You did not include any error message from curl or wget. Please show them.

Comment: Line 8, there should be "iface" rather than "auto"

Comment: Ok, I updated the iface line and that succeeded in restarting networking (@JohnRonald) but it did not fix the curl/wget problem.


Here is the curl error @raj




--2021-02-08 14:56:03--  (try: 6)  http://www.reddit.com/
Connecting to www.reddit.com (www.reddit.com)|151.101.1.140|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.reddit.com (www.reddit.com)|151.101.65.140|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.reddit.com (www.reddit.com)|151.101.129.140|:80...

Comment: What command exactly do you use ?

Comment: wget https://www.reddit.com
--2021-02-08 15:32:03--  https://www.reddit.com/
Resolving www.reddit.com (www.reddit.com)... 151.101.1.140, 151.101.65.140, 151.101.129.140, ...
Connecting to www.reddit.com (www.reddit.com)|151.101.1.140|:443...@johnronald

Comment: It (wget) doesn't work for me either for that site. Other sites work fine. your curl example didn't try port 443. they don't seems to have http, only https.

Comment: Same problem for every site I try :-( @doug-smythies

wget http://google.com
--2021-02-08 21:51:56--  http://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 172.217.0.174, 2607:f8b0:4008:811::200e
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|172.217.0.174|:80... http://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 172.217.0.174, 2607:f8b0:4008:811::200e
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|172.217.0.174|:80...^

Answer (score 0):

this is my running config:

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto eno2
iface eno2 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
bond-mode 4
bond-miimon 100
bond-xmit_hash_policy layer3+4
bond-lacp-rate 1
bond-slaves eno1 eno2